# Angular NGRX effects- map code block executed w/o waiting for HttpResponse

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, ngrx-effects

Created effect in NgRX as below, and expecting behavior as:

1. code in map block should be executed only if http response is successful
2. code in catchError block should be executed only if response is unsuccessful
   However code in map block is executed immediately after request code is executed without waiting for response.

Effect code is as below

```
  @Effect()
  uploadRequestEffect$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.ActionTypes.UPLOAD_REQUEST),
    map((action: actions.UploadRequestAction) => action.payload),
    switchMap(state => {
      return this.uploadApiClient.upload(state).pipe(
        map(() =>new actions.UploadCompletedAction()),
        catchError(error => of(new actions.UploadFailureAction(error)))
      )
    }));
```

Because of code in map execution , UploadCompleteAction is triggered and updating HTML component updating message "File upload completed". however request is yet to be send.

Catch error block triggers appropriately when error occurs but map block executed regardless.
FYI. I've HttpRequest interceptor code, which adds token to headers before sending request.
Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Is it possible, that `upload` emits something before the upload is finished? Can you please add its code?

Comment: Thanks mat.hudak. You correctly directed me as upload emits something else. Actually I migrated old code from http to httpclient which has multiple httpevents. In my case before response event, other events are emitted causing this issue. Thanks.